# Writing a reference in the beamer's slides

Tags: beamer, bibliographies

I want to refer to some papers in the slides by writing the whole details of the paper as in the picture, Could you help with that please? [image]

Comment: You need to use bib(la)tex for that

Comment: @DG' Thank you. Is that a bibliography with one element?

Answer (score 1):

If you use the `biblatex` package for your bibliographies (note that this requires to compile with `biber` instead of `bibtex`), you have a couple of possibilities.

- if you just need the full information and not necessarily the same formatting as in the bibliography, you could use the `\fullcite{...}` macro
- if you actually need it to look like a bibliography, you could e.g. use the `refsection` environment to create a local bibliography

---

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\fullcite{westfahl:space}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\begin{refsection}
\nocite{knuth:ct}\printbibliography
\end{refsection}
\end{frame}
    
\end{document}
```

[image]